# A normal random variable independent of each component of a multivariate normal random vector.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

Suppose that $\mathbf{Y}\sim N_3(0,\,\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_3)$ and that $Y_0$ is $N(0,\,\sigma_0^2)$, independently of the $Y_i$'s.
My question is that does $(\mathbf{Y}, Y_0)$ also have multivariate normal distribution? By using moment generating function, it suffices that $\mathbf Y$ and $Y_0$ are independent. But is this the case?

Comment: You have two answers saying *yes* and *no*.  The difference depends on what precisely you mean by $Y_0$ being independent of the $Y_i$s, individually or collectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not: there can exist random variables which are individually Gaussian, and pairwise independent, but not jointly Gaussian.  Let $X_0,X_1,X_2,X_3$ be iid $N(0,1)$.  Now let $$(Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)=(|X_0|\operatorname{sgn}(X_1 X_2 X_3), X_1, X_2,X_3),$$ where $\operatorname{sgn} (X_1 X_2 X_3)=\pm1$ according to the sign of  $X_1X_2X_3$. One can check that $Y_0$ is Gaussian, and independent of each of the other individual $Y_i$. Why is $Y_0$ Gaussian?  Well, its absolute value is distributed as the absolute value of an $N(0,1)$ rv, and that its sign is uniformly distributed on $\pm1$.  Why is it independent of (say) $Y_1$, that is, of $X_1$?  Because $X_2$ and $X_3$ obliterate any control $X_1$ might hold over $\operatorname{sgn} (X_1 X_2 X_3).$  And finally, why are the $Y_i$ not jointly Gaussian?  Well, their product is $\ge0$ with probability $1$.

This is similar to the example of $T=RS$ when $R$ and $S$ are iid uniform $\pm1$ rvs, three rvs which are pairwise independent but not jointly independent.

Answer (score 0):

This is true. To verify this, you can check that any of the [equivalent definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Equivalent_definitions) of the multivariate normal distribution hold. (Checking the MGF is one of them.)

Edit: In light of kimchi lover's answer, I should mention that I am assuming $Y_0$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are independent, which is stronger than assuming that the pair $Y_0$ and $Y_i$ are independent for each $i$.